# Getting classes from an assembly outside of web project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 4`, `C#` and `AutoMapper`.  In my global.asax.cs I am trying to register my mappings from another project (a C# project referenced in my web app).

In this other project I have my mappings, here is a sample class:

```
namespace MyProject.Web.Core.Mappings
{
     public class EmployeeMapping
     {
          public EmployeeMapping()
          {
               Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeInfoViewModel>();
          }
     }
}
```

In my global.asax.cs I have a method where I want to load these mappings. The code below I got online, but it is not picking up my mapping classes, in this case EmployeeMapping:

```
protected void AutoMapperConfig()
{
     string mappingNamespace = "MyProject.Web.Core.Mappings";

     var q = from t in Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(string))
             where t.IsClass && t.Namespace == mappingNamespace
             select t;

     q.ForEach(t => Debug.WriteLine(t.Name));
}
```

How do I get my classes in a specific namespace (from another project other than the web project) and use `Activator.CreateInstance`?

All that I want is a list of the classes that are specified in the namespace given.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I get my classes in a specific namespace (from another project other than the web project) and use Activator.CreateInstance?

Assuming you know *one* of the types in the assembly, you can use:

```
var types = typeof(TheTypeYouKnowAbout).Assembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t.Namespace == "TheNamespaceYouWant");
                // Possibly add more restrictions, e.g. it must be
                // public, and a class rather than an interface, and
                // must have a public parameterless constructor...
foreach (var type in types)
{
    // Do something with the type
}
```

(If you can give more information about what you're trying to do, it will be easier to help you in more detail.)

Comment: What do you mean by type? These are all classes.

Comment: @BrendanVogt: Classes *are* types - if you only want classes, use `t.IsClass` as another filter.

Comment: I meant what do I put in the place of TheTypeYouKnowAbout?

Comment: @BrendanVogt: Any of the types in that assembly - that's what I meant at the start of the answer: "Assuming you know *one* of the types in the assembly"

Comment: I'm still not sure what I need to replace TheTypeYouKnowAbout with? Given the class above named EmployeeMapping thats all that I have in the namespace TheNamespaceYouWant. All that I know is that EmployeeMapping is a class. So do I replace `TheTypeYouKnowAbout` with `class`?

Comment: @BrendanVogt: It sound like you probably want `typeof(EmployeeMapping)` then. But if that's the only class in that namespace, why would you want *anything* other than `typeof(EmployeeMapping)`?

Comment: There are a couple of mapping classes, I just mentioned and show what 1 of the mapping classes look like.  How would I cater for a bunch of classes? They all reside in the same namepsace given in my post.

Comment: @BrendanVogt: You said: "Given the class above named EmployeeMapping thats all that I have in the namespace TheNamespaceYouWant" - either it's the only thing in the namespace or it's not. But if that's *an* example, then just change `typeof(TheTypeYouKnowAbout)` to `typeof(EmployeeMapping)` in the sample code I've given. Make sure you *understand* the code though - it feels like at the moment you're not really clear about what everything's doing.

Comment: I'm still not sure what needs to be put in TheTypeYouKnowAbout. Does it become class? Yes it is all that I currently have in that namespace as I have not developed the app further than this point. I think there is a communication gap on both sides here.

Comment: All that I want is the classes that reside in the namespace that I specified. And given that these are just classes should I replace `TheTypeYouKnowAbout` with the word `class`? If you see the class that I specified, what would you replace `TheTypeYouKnowAbout` with? All the code that I have is in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(string))`, it loads the types in mscorlib.dll  and nothing would be returned from the linq query you provided. You would need to load the assembly using `typeof(EmployeeMapping).Assembly` or `Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(EmployeeMapping))` or `Assembly.LoadFrom("YourAssemblyName.dll")` in order to query the types of that particular assembly.

EDIT:

To further answer your question...assuming you know all the types that are responsible for mapping and the assemblies they are contained in.

```
protected void AutoMapperConfig()
{
    const string mappingNamespace = "MyProject.Web.Core.Mappings";

    //There are ways to accomplish this same task more efficiently.
    var q = (from t in Assembly.LoadFrom("YourAssemblyName.dll").GetExportedTypes()
             where t.IsClass && t.Namespace == mappingNamespace
             select t).ToList();

    //Assuming all the types in this namespace have defined a
    //default constructor. Otherwise, this iterative call will
    //eventually throw a TypeLoadException (I believe) because
    //the arguments for any of the possible constructors for the
    //type were not provided in the call to Activator.CreateInstance(t) 
    q.ForEach(t => Activator.CreateInstance(t));
}
```

But if you're referencing the assemblies in your web project...I'd go with the below or some sort of IoC/DI framework to instantiation the mapping classes, if the types were unknown at compiletime.

```cs
protected void AutoMapperConfig()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeInfoViewModel>();
    //Repeat the above for other "mapping" classes.
    //Mapper.CreateMap<OtherType, OtherViewModel>();
}
```

EDIT Given first of @Brendan Vogt Comments:

```
public interface IMappingHandler
{
}

//NOTE: None of this code was tested...but it'll be close(ish)..

protected void AutoMapperConfig()
{
    //If the assemblies are located in the bin directory:
    var assemblies = Directory.GetFiles(HttpRuntime.BinDirectory, "*.dll");

    //Otherwise, use something like the following:
    var assemblies = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\SomeDirectory\\", "*.dll");

    //Define some sort of other filter...a base type for example.
    var baseType = typeof(IMappingHandler);

    foreach (var file in assemblies)
    {
        //There are other ways to optimize this query.
        var types = (from t in Assembly.LoadFrom(file).GetExportedTypes()
                     where t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && baseType.IsAssignableFrom(t)
                     select t).ToList();

        //Assuming all the queried types defined a default constructor.
        types.ForEach(t => Activator.CreateInstance(t));
    }
}
```

Comment: To add a note from @Jon Skeet's answer. Assembly.GetTypes() loads all types contained in the assembly (public, private, internal, etc). Calling Assembly.GetExportedTypes() will only return public types.

Comment: I don't want to specify the class name like EmployeeMapping because there are other mapping classes as well. Code will be too much. I don't want to specify the .dll as well because what happens if I have mapping classes in other projects besides this one?

Comment: It's not a mapping question and how I do mapping, all that I want is a list of classes in the namespace given. How I eventually decide to do the mapping is up to me, but for now I just need a list of the classes in the namespace that I specified.

Comment: The above code will give you a set of classes within all assemblies in the specified directory that inherit from the `IMappingHandler` interface. If you'd like to filter by namespace, then add that to the criteria of the linq query.